# loading value into a select?

Tags: php, html, forms

when loading my form (from variables) i can easily set the value of most text form items with the value tag like this:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?php print "$fname";?>" />
```

how can i do the same with **select** input form elements? i guess i have to use a script?

thanks a lot

Comment: Why the unnecessary quotes/interpolation around `$fname`? Also, you need `htmlspecialchars()` every time you echo out text strings into HTML, or you risk HTML-injection XSS vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `selected` attribute to the selected option, e.g.

```
<option value="foo" 
        <?php echo ($value=="foo") ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?> > 
    bar 
</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

A select element is a parent of the option element, right?
If so, all you need to do is make the option have the selected attribute.

Instead of

```
<select>
  <option>BLAAARRGGHHHH</option>
  <option>ZAAAAAAAAARGGGH</option>
  <option>NAARGHHH</option
</select>
```

you have

```
<select>
  <option>BLAAARRGGHHHH</option>
  <option selected="selected">ZAAAAAAAAARGGGH</option>
  <option>NAARGHHH</option
</select>
```

to make "ZAAAAAAAAARGGGH" selected

Comment: Haven't used <select> and <option> for quite a while, sorry if I'm not correctly answering your question.